# Change environment variable (TERM)

Tags: environment-variables, terminator

According to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/3004/148598), "it is the job of the terminal emulator to set the TERM environment variable".

Is there any way to change the TERM value used by Terminator? Right now it's `xterm`, but I need `xterm-256color`.

I use other terminal emulators (Gnome Terminator, tmux), so setting in my .bashrc would be messy at best.

Answer (score 10):

The way I do it is using a `custom_command` in `~/.config/terminator/config` as follows:

```
...
[profiles]
  [[default]]
    ...
    custom_command = TERM=xterm-256color bash -l # Do not use 'terminator' here
    use_custom_command = True
    ...
```

This works like a charm i.e. for the 256-color skins for
[midnight commander](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yk52.png). The `-l` option makes bash run as a login shell (which means that it will load settings from your `.bash_profile`).  You can omit it if you prefer Terminator to launch bash as a non-login shell (so that it will load `.bashrc` instead).

Answer (score 6):

There's an option called `xterm` in Terminator's configuration (see `man terminator_config`), which is supposed to set `TERM`. [Due to](https://answers.launchpad.net/terminator/+question/235355) [a bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=640940#c14), it does not work, and `TERM` is always set to `xterm`. Terminator also sets a `COLORTERM` variable, to `gnome-terminal`, so you can use that to set `TERM` to `xterm-256color` (since `gnome-terminal` has no problem with that value:

```
[[ $COLORTERM = gnome-terminal ]] && TERM=xterm-256color
```

Or, what I use to avoid problems with `screen`/`tmux`:

```
[[ $COLORTERM = gnome-terminal && ! $TERM = screen-256color ]] && TERM=xterm-256color
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an untested idea:

- Copy `/usr/share/applications/terminator.desktop` to `~/.local/share/applications`
- [Edit the local .desktop copy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144968/set-variable-in-desktop-file) so it sets TERM when starting terminator

Comment: Negative. While this works for setting environment variables in general, Terminator itself sets TERM anyway, so it gets overwritten.

Comment: @dafrazzman: Hmm.. I thought it was not set at all. So, if terminator sets it to xterm while xterm-256color is needed, isn't it a bug in terminator?