# Term Enviroment variable not set

Tags: 12.04, scripts

This is the code that I want to execute through motd:

```
#!/bin/bash
IP=`ifconfig  | grep 'inet addr:'| grep -v '127.0.0.1' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}'`
#clear
echo -e "Welcome to \e[0;32mDMS 4\e[0m"
echo
echo -e "Connect with your Browser to following IP-Address: \e[0;32mhttp://$IP\e[0m"
echo
echo "If no IP-Address is shown above then"
echo "maybe there is no DHCP-Server available in your network."
echo "If so you have to change the IP to a static Address."
echo -e "Just type \e[0;32mnetconf\e[0m and press Enter"
```

I placed `/usr/sbin/autologin-screen` (location of the script) in my `00-header` file under the `/etc/update-motd.d` folder.
Does anyone have an idea why I am getting this error:

```
TERM environment variable not set
```

Note* Removing Clear removed 1 error.  I still have another `TERM environment variable not set`

Comment: What does `clear` and `shift` and `exec $*` do?

Comment: @Tim I forgot, I do not actually use those lines, they were specific to another distro.  I edit them out of my initial post.  See what copy paste does lol.

Comment: And the clear is suppose to clear the terminal screen.

Comment: @Keith - you could just take out the `cat /etc/issue` line... (why is that needed anyway?).

Comment: @Wilf  Just wanted to display the issue, but it does already display it on boot.  Taking it out however did not fix the TERM enviroment issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [motd manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/motd.5.html):

> ```
>    The  contents of /etc/motd are displayed by login(1) after a 
>    successful login but just before it executes the login shell.
> ```

according to [login manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/login.1.html):

> ```
>    On some installations, the environmental variable $TERM will be
>    initialized to the terminal type on your tty line, as specified in
>    /etc/ttytype.
> ```

and according to [clear manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/clear.1.html):

> ```
>    It looks in the environment for the terminal type and then in the
>    terminfo database to  figure out how to clear the screen.
> ```

I guess that TERM variable is set after your **motd** scripts execution and because of this, **clear** command print `TERM environment variable not set`.

On lubuntu 12.04 I tested this by `unset TERM` and exec `clear`. In this condition I obtain same error.

Comment: Removing the clear command did remove a `TERM enviroment variable not set`.  I did however have that error pop up twice and I still have one left.  I will look into something else maybe creating the problem.

Comment: I don't think that your motd script prints that error now. Could you check file in `/etc/update-motd.d` directory ? Also `.bashrc`, `.profile`. Once you are logged in, is `$TERM` correctly set? try `echo $TERM`

Comment: `echo $TERM` prints `linux`.  Is this correct.  I am going to look into those other files now.

Comment: I found where the error was.  In my `00-header` file I had a clear.  Commented it out and it works fine now.  Thanks for the tips!

Comment: linux value is right if you are using getty. [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2995/how-is-the-default-term-shell-variable-value-set) is some useful information.