# 14.04 inside docker "TERM environment variable not set"

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

I am running an ubuntu 14.04 inside a docker container. My image is build from the official ubuntu:14.04 image) The Docker file is almost identical with this https://github.com/pfy/erpnext/blob/master/Dockerfile (just changed FROM debian:wheezy >>> FROM ubuntu:14.04).

[ERPNext](http://www.erpnext.com) is being installed using this script https://raw.githubusercontent.com/frappe/bench/master/install_scripts/setup_frappe.sh).

The build and run instruction to be found here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pfy/erpnext/master/README.md

Somehow it is working but the terminal/console seems not to be fully functional.

i.e. I get a `"TERM environment variable not set"` when I try to `clear`the screen. 
I found some other posts with the same or similar error message but the context is always different, so I can't get anything from the solutions offered.

I guess the docker ubuntu images might be used pretty frequent, so maybe someone has encountered and solved this issue.

Comment: `TERM` should be [set by the terminal emulator](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2995/how-is-the-default-term-shell-variable-value-set). Which terminal emulator are you using?

Comment: honestly. no idea which terminal emulator I am using. I didn't install any and I don't think the scripts that ran to install ERPNext install any. So it should be what is 'shipped' with the ubuntu:14.04 docker image.

Comment: I found out that this problem doesn't exist when running a container from the fresh ubuntu:14.04 image. So it seems it occurs somehow through the ERPNext installation. I can't identify anything responsible for such in the scripts that are being run. I don't understand too much of them though I should add.

Comment: just a thought: there is no Desktop environment, so is there a terminal emulator involved at all ?

Comment: It was you who mentioned "terminal/concole". The default terminal eliminator in Ubuntu is gnome-terminal and the default user shell is bash. Without really understanding the implications of the docker, a workaround might possibly be to add `export TERM=xterm` at the top of .bashrc.

Answer (score 4):

Short of having to edit a config after launching the container, instead you can just define the missing environment variable when you run the debian based container

```
-e TERM=xterm
```

as in this example

```
export DUMMY_SERVER_NAME=itswednesday

docker run \
  -d \
  --name $DUMMY_SERVER_NAME \
  -e TERM=xterm \
  --expose=80 \
  debian /bin/bash -c "while [[ true ]]; do sleep 1; done"
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks to the comments from **`Gunnar Hjalmarsson`** this is what seems to solve the issue

```
docker start [container]
docker exec -it [container] bash
vim /etc/bash.bashrc
```

adding `export TERM=xterm` to the top of the file, stopping/restarting my container ...

e voila! ... the terminal seems to behave 'normal' (which I tested by using the `clear` command which didn't work before and now does)

thanks again and sorry for introducing misleading terms (terminal/console) in my original post.

Comment: Glad to hear that you could fix it that way.

Answer (score 0):

This will be fixed in Docker 1.13 via [this pull request](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/26461) that was recently merged. Until you run that version, you can run `exec` commands like so, to avoid this problem:

```
docker exec --tty [container] env TERM=xterm [command-to-run]
```